# Distribution of a function of two random variables given by Poisson and Binomial distribution get's complicated

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, random-functions

*Suppose that particles are emitted by a radioactive source and that the number of particles emitted over a period of one hour is given by a Poisson distribution with parameter λ. Admit that a metering device, which registers these emissions, occasionally fails to register an emitted particle. Specifically, suppose any emitted particle has a probability p of being registered.
a) If Y is defined as the number of registered particles, what is the expression for the probability distribution of Y?*

My approach to this question was the standard way to handle functions of two random variables, by making $Y=N-R$, where $N$ is the number of particles emitted and $R$  is the number of particles registered, then finding an auxiliary function $Y'$ to form the joint distribution $p(y, y')$, calculating the determinant of the Jacobian $J(n,r)$ and then finding the following distribution:

$p_{Y,Y'} = \frac{1}{|J(n,r)|}p_{N,R}(G_1(y,y'), G_2(y, y'))$

where $y =  H_{1}(n, r) $, $y' =  H_{2}(n, r), $ $n = G_{1}(y, y')$ and $r = G_{2}(y, y')$.

And then, to find $p_Y$, I sum over all possible values of $Y'$.

What I want to know is if this is correct. Since N and R are given by a Poisson and a Binomial, it got kind of complicated to sum over all values of $Y'$ in the  joint distribution $p_{N,R}$.  I'm wondering if this approach is the only one (and correct) or if there is a simpler way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems overly complicated, but maybe I am misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

The way I see it, you should marginalize over the number of emitted particles, since the number of registered particles $R$ conditioned on the number of emitted particles $N=n$ is distributed as Bin($n,p$), while $N$ itself is Poisson($\lambda$). Thus by the total probability formula,

$$P(R=r)=\sum_{i=r}^\infty f_{\mathrm{Bin}}(r;i,p) f_{\mathrm{Poisson}}(i;\lambda)$$

where $f_{\mathrm{Bin}}$ is the binomial PMF and $f_{\mathrm{Poisson}}$ is the Poisson PMF. This can actually be simplified:

$$P(R=r)=\sum_{i=r}^\infty {i \choose r} p^r q^{i-r} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!} \\ 
= \frac{e^{-\lambda} (p\lambda)^r}{r!} \sum_{i=r}^\infty \frac{(q\lambda)^{i-r}}{(i-r)!} \\
= \frac{e^{-p\lambda} (p\lambda)^r}{r!}.$$

Thus you find that you have just the Poisson($p\lambda$) PMF, which is nice and intuitive.

Comment: Damn, you are right. For some reason I was considering the difference between emitted particles and registered particles to be... the number of registered particles. How I got to this conclusion? Go figure. Guess I will delete the question out of shame.